# Tomcat service active but exited

Tags: java, android, linux, web-services, tomcat8

When I started tomcat on linux server,approximately after a day,tomcat shutdown and it shows status like active(exited).Can u help me pls? 
I have already log :

```
tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2017-06-10 12:23:52 UTC; 1 day 18h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Jun 10 12:23:47 ip-172-31-7-212 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start Tomcat..
Jun 10 12:23:47 ip-172-31-7-212 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
Jun 10 12:23:47 ip-172-31-7-212 tomcat8[22872]:  * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat8
Jun 10 12:23:52 ip-172-31-7-212 tomcat8[22872]:    ...done.
Jun 10 12:23:52 ip-172-31-7-212 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Tomcat..
ubuntu@ip-172-31-7-212:~$
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with slightly older versions of Tomcat would lead me to believe there could be a memory leak with the application. At least as recently as Tomcat 6, we would have issues where the server would run out of memory and would not report anything of the sort. It would stay active, but stop processing requests.

You should try to profile the memory usage of your application to see if it grows over time. If this is a production system, institute scheduled restarts in the meantime while the memory leak is being debugged.